# Gráfico Pie, ¿cómo pasar los datos de json php al pie?

Tags: php, javascript, json, pdo, chart.js

Me pueden ayudar, por favor.

tengo el siguiente php, obtengo los datos y lo convierto a json.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once 'controller.php';
$auht = new system();

$posts = array();
$sql = $auth->runQuery("SELECT COUNT(cs.tipo) AS contidad, cl.nombre FROM conser cs LEFT JOIN clientes cl ON cs.idcliente = cl.idcliente WHERE (tipo='Servicio' AND baul='1') GROUP BY cs.idcliente ORDER BY nombre ASC");
$sql->execute();
while ($row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $posts[] = $row;
    }
echo json_encode($posts);
```

Los datos que me devuelve el json.

```
[{"cantidad":"1","nombre":"Cliente1"},{"cantidad":"17","nombre":"Cliente2"},{"cantidad":"1","nombre":"Cliente3"},
{"cantidad":"4","nombre":"Cliente4"},{"cantidad":"7","nombre":"Cliente5"},{"cantidad":"1","nombre":"Cliente6"},
{"cantidad":"3","nombre":"Cliente7"},{"cantidad":"1","nombre":"Cliente8"},{"cantidad":"11","nombre":"Cliente9"},{"cantidad":"2","nombre":"Cliente10"}]
```

hasta aquí todo bien; pero no se como puedo llamarlo al script para poder llenar los datos en el Gráfico en Pie.

Nota: este ejemplo en pie en inter, y quiero adapatarlo a mi necesidad.

```
    // Define elements
    var pie_basic_element = document.getElementById('pie_basic');

    // Basic pie chart
    if (pie_basic_element) {

        // Initialize chart
        var pie_basic = echarts.init(pie_basic_element);

        // Chart config

        pie_basic.setOption({

            // Add legend
            legend: {
                orient: 'vertical',
                top: 'center',
                left: 0,
                data: ['IE', 'Opera', 'Safari', 'Firefox', 'Chrome'],
                itemHeight: 8,
                itemWidth: 8
            },

            // Add series
            series: [{
                name: 'Browsers',
                type: 'pie',
                radius: '70%',
                center: ['50%', '57.5%'],
                itemStyle: {
                    normal: {
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderColor: '#fff'
                    }
                },

      // entiendo que aqui es donde va el json, pero no puedo conectarlo...
                data: [
                    {value: 335, name: 'IE'},
                    {value: 310, name: 'Opera'},
                    {value: 234, name: 'Safari'},
                    {value: 135, name: 'Firefox'},
                    {value: 1548, name: 'Chrome'}

                ]
            }]
        });
    }
```

Como dije anteriormente, no se como puedo añadir los datos que traigo del json, esto lo hago para que puedo actualizarse de manera automatica sin necesidad de refrescar la web.

Gracias por su apoyo.
y este es el resultado del PIE,pero quiero mostrar mis datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para poder ayudarte mejor adjunta el codigo JSON que estas recibiendo de tu consulta, el nombre y ruta de la libreria de JS que carga el grafico Pie

Comment: Hola Alexander, incluí el json arriba, y aquí están los datos todo el pie, espero me puedas ayudar. https://we.tl/t-xYZN03HjtD

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente logre entender la libreria de graficos echarts con lo que tengo una respuesta a tu pregunta.

Link de la libreria grafica: https://we.tl/t-xYZN03HjtD

**AJUSTES:**

1) Tuve que sacar la variable involucrada con la carga de la grafica para que pudiera ser accedida de una forma mas eficiente al colocarle datos por JSON

2) Modifique la funcion de ejecucion de la grafica por otra funcion que se puede llamar en cualquer momento que reciba datos, haciendo de la grafica una actualizacion dinamica.

**EXPLICACION:**

Aqui te coloco una pequeña guia para que uses la libreria y puedas colocarle los datos que necesitas, lo que seria recibiendo la informacion mediante del AJAX el cual te pasara los datos por JSON.

**COLOCAR DATOS en el Pie chart** (variable base: **datosParaPie**)

**(1) ITEMS:** ver/colocar Los items del grafico estructura: 
        `{value: 335, name: "IE"}`  <-- (los nombres value y name deben ser los mismos)

```
      datosParaPie.series[0].data[]
```

**(2) Colores:** paleta de colores para los elementos del pie: 
 es un array numerico, los colores son hexadecimales y van usandose en el orden de cada item, en la tabla demo son 20 ejemplares.

Ejemplo para asignar color en casilla 0: `datosParaPie.color[0]="#ffb980";`

**(3) titulo:** coloca el titulo del grafico de pie

```
datosParaPie.title.text
```

**(4) subtitulo:** coloca el subtitulo del grafico de pie

```
datosParaPie.title.subtext
```

**(5) titulo de la ventana flotante** negra que aparece al apuntar un item del grafico

```
datosParaPie.series[0].name
```

**(6) leyenda:** es una variable array numeric que se coloca cada item y debe tener el
mismo nombre que se asigno al item para que pueda aparecer

Ejemplo:

```
datosParaPie.series[0].data[0]={value: 435, name: "WE"} ;
datosParaPie.legend.data[0]="WE";
```

Sintaxis:

```
datosParaPie.legend.data[]
```

Adjunto ejemplo con los cambios para cargar el grafico por JSON:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
        <!-- Global stylesheets -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components.min.css">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="echarts/echarts.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Basic pie -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="chart-container">
                            <div class="chart has-fixed-height" id="pie_basic"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- / Basic pie -->

        <script type="text/javascript">

        // VARIABLE PARA CARGAR DATOS AL GRAFICO
        // Define elements
        var pie_basic_element = document.getElementById('pie_basic');
        var pie_basic = null; // variable de configuracion
        var datosParaPie = {

                        // Colors
                        color: [
                            '#2ec7c9','#b6a2de','#5ab1ef','#ffb980','#d87a80',
                            '#8d98b3','#e5cf0d','#97b552','#95706d','#dc69aa',
                            '#07a2a4','#9a7fd1','#588dd5','#f5994e','#c05050',
                            '#59678c','#c9ab00','#7eb00a','#6f5553','#c14089'
                        ],

                        // Global text styles
                        textStyle: {
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif',
                            fontSize: 13
                        },

                        // Add title
                        title: {
                            text: 'Browser popularity',
                            subtext: 'Open source information',
                            left: 'center',
                            textStyle: {
                                fontSize: 17,
                                fontWeight: 500
                            },
                            subtextStyle: {
                                fontSize: 12
                            }
                        },

                        // Add tooltip
                        tooltip: {
                            trigger: 'item',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
                            padding: [10, 15],
                            textStyle: {
                                fontSize: 13,
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif'
                            },
                            formatter: "{a} <br/>{b}: {c} ({d}%)"
                        },

                        // Add legend
                        legend: {
                            orient: 'vertical',
                            top: 'center',
                            left: 0,
                            data: ['IE', 'Opera', 'Safari', 'Firefox', 'Chrome'],
                            itemHeight: 8,
                            itemWidth: 8
                        },

                        // Add series
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Browsers',
                            type: 'pie',
                            radius: '70%',
                            center: ['50%', '57.5%'],
                            itemStyle: {
                                normal: {
                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                    borderColor: '#fff'
                                }
                            },
                            data: [

                                {value: 335, name: 'IE'},
                                {value: 310, name: 'Opera'},
                                {value: 234, name: 'Safari'},
                                {value: 135, name: 'Firefox'},
                                {value: 1548, name: 'Chrome'}
                            ]
                        }]
                        };
            // fin datosParaPie

        //
        // Charts configuration
        //



    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var EchartsPiesDonuts = function(pie_basic_element) {
    //
    // Setup module components
    //

    // Pie and donut charts
    var _piesDonutsExamples = function(pie_basic_element) {
        if (typeof echarts == 'undefined') {
            console.warn('Warning - echarts.min.js is not loaded.');
            return;
        }

        //
        // Resize charts
        //

        // Resize function
        var triggerChartResize = function() {
            pie_basic_element && pie_basic.resize();

        };

        // On sidebar width change
        $(document).on('click', '.sidebar-control', function() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                triggerChartResize();
            }, 0);
        });

        // On window resize
        var resizeCharts;
        window.onresize = function () {
            clearTimeout(resizeCharts);
            resizeCharts = setTimeout(function () {
                triggerChartResize();
            }, 200);
        };

    };
    // fin de _piesDonutsExamples

    return {
        init: function() {
            _piesDonutsExamples();
        }
    }
};


// funcion para correr PieChart;
function runPieChart() {
    // Este es el que ejecuta el pieChart Basic pie chart
    if (pie_basic_element) {
            // Initialize chart
            pie_basic = echarts.init(pie_basic_element);
            // Options
            pie_basic.setOption(datosParaPie);
    }  
}

    // ya se recibieron los datos
    datosEntradaJSON=[{value:"1",name:"Cliente1"},{value:"17",name:"Cliente2"},{value:"1",name:"Cliente3"},
                    {value:"4",name:"Cliente4"},{value:"7",name:"Cliente5"},{value:"1",name:"Cliente6"},
                    {value:"3",name:"Cliente7"},{value:"1",name:"Cliente8"},{value:"11",name:"Cliente9"},
                    {value:"2",name:"Cliente10"}];

    // borrar datos de prueba 
    datosParaPie.legend.data.length=0;
    datosParaPie.series[0].data.length=0;
    // cargar los datos recibidos
    for (let index = 0; index < datosEntradaJSON.length; index++) {
        datosParaPie.series[0].data.push(datosEntradaJSON[index]);  // para items
        datosParaPie.legend.data.push(datosEntradaJSON[index]["name"]); // para leyenda
    }

    // ejecucion del grafico Pie
    runPieChart();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

La salida del codigo es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]